# UI-GRID-info Expandable grid with button and action

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Can I have a button in Angular UI-GRID-info expandable sub-grid and call a function like getExternalScopes().Validate or SaveRow, or DelteRow?

```
{name: 'saveRow', cellTemplate: '<button id="saveBtn" type="button"  ng-click="getExternalScopes().saveRow(row.entity)" >Save</button> '}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is quite unclear, please add some more information. A few lines of source code are often better than 1000 words :)

Comment: Added an example code line for subgrid column definition - cellTemplate to call function through getExternalScopes()

Answer (score 2):

I already fixed in the plunker above Must have `appScopeProvider: $scope` in `subGridOptions` http://plnkr.co/edit/VHuE151KUFx0ImVPuHy2?p=preview

Comment: the plunkr example did not work for me, but the advice is correct i.e adding appScopeProvider: $scope to my subGridOptions made the buttons call the correct method with entity/parameters passed.